# Printing the part of speech along with the synonyms of the word

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have the following code for taking a word from the input text file and printing the synonyms, definitions and example sentences for the word using WordNet. It separates the synonyms from the synset based on the part-of-speech, i.e., the synonyms that are verbs and the synonyms that are adjectives are printed separately.

Example for the word flabbergasted the synonyms are 1) flabbergast , boggle , bowl over which are verbs and 2)dumbfounded , dumfounded , flabbergasted , stupefied , thunderstruck , dumbstruck , dumbstricken which are adjectives.

How do I print the part-of-speech along with the synonyms? I have provided the code I have so far below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
fp = open('sample.txt','r')
data = fp.read()
tokens= nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(data)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
words = [w.lower() for w in text]
for a in words:
   print a 
syns = wn.synsets(a)
for s in syns:
   print 
   print "definition:" s.definition
   print "synonyms:"
   for l in s.lemmas:
      print l.name
   print "examples:"
   for b in s.examples:
      print b
   print
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `pos()` on a synset. To list all the POS for a lemma:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> syns = wn.synsets('dog')
>>> set([x.pos() for x in syns])
{'n', 'v'}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere except the [source code](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html), which shows other methods that can be called on a synset.

> Synset attributes, accessible via methods with the same name:
>
> - `name`: The canonical name of this synset, formed using the first lemma   of this synset. Note that this may be different from the name 
>     passed to the constructor if that string used a different lemma to
>     identify the synset.
> - `pos`: The synset's part of speech, matching one of the module level   attributes ADJ, ADJ_SAT, ADV, NOUN or VERB.
> - `lemmas`: A list of the Lemma objects for this synset.
> - `definition`: The definition for this synset.
> - `examples`: A list of example strings for this synset.
> - `offset`: The offset in the WordNet dict file of this synset.
> - `lexname`: The name of the lexicographer file containing this synset.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you messed up your indentation:

```
for a in words:
   print a 
syns = wn.synsets(a)
```

Seems like `syns = wn.synsets(a)` should be inside the `words` for loop so you can do this for every word:

```
for w in words:
    print w
    syns = wn.synsets(w)
    for s in syns:
        print
        print "definition:", s.definition
        print "synonyms:"
        for l in s.lemmas:
            print l.name
        print "examples:"
        for b in s.examples:
            print b
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

A lemma has a `synset` attribute, which has its own part of speech in its `pos` attribute. So, if we have a lemma as `l`, we can access its part of spech like this:

```
>>> l = Lemma('gladden.v.01.joy')
>>> l.synset.pos
'v'
```

More generally, we can extend this into a loop to read through your file. I'm using the `with` statement because it closes files nicely once the loop is completed.

```
>>> with open('sample.txt') as f:
...     raw = f.read()
...     for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(raw):
...         sentence = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sentence)
...         for word in sentence:
...             for synset in wn.synsets(word):
...                 for lemma in synset.lemmas:
...                     print lemma.name, lemma.synset.pos
...
```

If you want to make sure that you are only choosing lemmas with the same part of speech as the word that you are currently talking about, then you will need to identify that word's part of speech too:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> with open('sample.txt') as f:
...     raw = f.read()
...     for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(raw):
...         sentence = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sentence))
...         for word, pos in sentence:
...             print word, pos
```

I'll leave reconciling these two as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: the pos function is giving me the following error:  lemma.synset.pos
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pos'

Comment: Thanks for the note. The NLTK API has changed since I wrote this answer. I'll find some time to update this answer.

Comment: can you tell me the function that can give pos using lemma with synset